# Clothes simulator is extremely slow and not working properly

Tags: modeling, modifiers, physics, cloth-simulation

Hi I'm a newbie and I was trying to create some clothes.

I couldn't find the play button so I just pressed the <kbd>Space</kbd> and it  kind of works but for some reason it seems like the clothes simulator is not working properly, whenever I use the clothes simulator the fps is like 7~9 frames. I was guessing maybe it's because of my character so I used the decimate geometry thing to reduce the file size but there's no big difference. But for sure once I imported the character to Blender, everything started to slow down and started lagging a lot. I don't know why this is happening.

[image: Clothes simulator not working properly]

Comment: Your simulation is running and maybe due to high geometry or simulation complexity it's slow.
it should run faster after it completes all the frames for first time

Comment: also you can drag from the bottom left corner to add a window and switch it to sequencer.
if your too lazy for that then hit + above and go to general>layout to add a new layout similar to the default one. :D

Comment: @Nand27  Hi !! thank you so much for the advice  I have a question tho... Do you know any other ways to reduce the character's high geometry ?? Oh and thanks to your help,  I added a new layout and changed it to sequence but for some reason I still can't see the play button  do you perhaps know what maybe the problem? once again thank you for your time and advice :)

Comment: I think it would be best to share a blend file, if the below answer didn't help.
You can share your blend file from here https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @Nand27 Thanks for helping out ! problem solved!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want two meshes, one for display(high poly), and one for the cloth simulation(low poly), so it is quicker and still looks good.

### One object only

First add a decimate modifier(in the modifiers tab, a blue wrench), to your object and change the ratio to something small(probably 0.1-0.3), and then a subdivision modifier, to make it high poly again.
There should already be a "collision" modifier. Put this between the decimate modifier and the subdivision modifier, so the low poly version of the mesh is used in the simulation, speeding it up.

### Two objects

If the previous solution makes your mesh look bad, then you will want two seperate objects, so you don't lose the orginal topology. First duplicate the mesh(alt-d), and parent it to the original mesh(select both objects, make sure the original is active(lighter orange, not red outline), and right click, make parent>object). remove the collision modifier from the original mesh, and add a decimate modifier *before* the collision modifier in the new mesh like above. This way the original mesh looks the same, but the simulation is using a low poly version.

### Make Cloth look better

To make the cloth look better, you will want to right click it and select "shade smooth"(so its not so bumpy). Now it will look a lot more realistic and less like low poly tin foil. You may also want to add a sudvision modifier(after the cloth modifier) to that as well, although this slows down the simulation in replay in my experiance.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice!! It really helped me a lot  Problem solved!